# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function in react-fontawesome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, font-awesome, react-font-awesome

Hellor there, I am working with react-fontawesome and webpack 4.33 version and I have this issue when I use a IconComponent it throws me an error TypeError: Object(...) is not a function.

It seems that the code points right here:

```js
var renderedIcon = Object(_fortawesome_fontawesome_svg_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["icon"])(iconLookup, _objectSpread({}, classes, transform, mask, {
    symbol: symbol,
    title: title
  }));
```

I have this in my webpack dev config file:

```js
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: path.resolve(__dirname,'src/index.js'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:9001/',
    chunkFilename: 'js/[id].[chunkhash].js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    open: true,
    port: 9001,
    hot: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpg|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|mp4|webm$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            outputPath: 'assets/',
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html')
    }),
  ],
}
```

I think I didn't add some configuration to my webpack file or should I report this as bug in the repository of react-fontawesome?

Comment: Yeah definitely add it as an issue. They are more likely to know what’s happened